# How represent in JsonML elements inside the text node

Tags: jsonml

Is [JsonML](http://jsonml.org) capable for describing markup such?

```
<data>
  text node a
  <innerdata>inner text node</innerdata>
  test node b
</data>
```

i.e. `innerdata` located in between of `data` inner text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. This is called [mixed mode xml](https://github.com/mckamey/jsonml#mixed-mode-xml). This is the entire reason that JsonML uses arrays instead of objects to represent elements. It needs to be able to support mixed mode XML and part of that is it needs to maintain the original order of the children. Mixed mode XML is rare in XML data but quite common in markup (e.g., HTML).

The specific structure you have there would be represented by the following JsonML:

```
["data",
    "text node a",
    ["innerData",
        "inner text node"],
    "test node b"
]
```

That assumes that you don't consider the tabs and newlines to be part of your example. Otherwise, if that whitespace is also significant, then something like this:

```
["data",
    "\n\ttext node a\n\t",
    ["innerData",
        "inner text node"],
    "\n\ttest node b\n"
]
```